# How to install font on asp.net razor webpage

Tags: asp.net, razor

I am trying to load ttf font before the page load so that user can type with that font in the form but no luck, I did create a folder called 'font' in the root of site and did add the line below in css but no luck, pls help

```
<style>
    @@font-face { 
        font-family: myfont !important; 
        src: url('/fonts/myfont.ttf') format("truetype"); }

</style>
```

Note: I am not doing MVC, just asp.net web page, thanks